# Pentaho "Get File Names" stopped working on Windows 2012 server from July 2019

Tags: pentaho

When I try to execute the GetFile names, it throws below error:
the exact same code works fine in Windows-7 box

Error is:

```
Transformation 2 - Loading transformation from XML file [file:///D:/Pentaho/CN-EAI-PentahoTool/sourceCode/BSCReadFilesInFolder.ktr]
2019/07/28 23:45:04 - readFilesInFolder - Dispatching started for transformation [readFilesInFolder]
2019/07/28 23:45:04 - Get rows from result.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=2, U=0, E=0)
2019/07/28 23:45:04 - Write to log.0 - 
2019/07/28 23:45:04 - Write to log.0 - ------------> Linenr 1------------------------------
2019/07/28 23:45:04 - Write to log.0 - folderrow = Y:\20190728
2019/07/28 23:45:04 - Write to log.0 - 
2019/07/28 23:45:04 - Write to log.0 - ====================
2019/07/28 23:45:04 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - Optimization level set to 9.
2019/07/28 23:45:04 - Write to log.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
2019/07/28 23:45:04 - FileInputList - ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : org.apache.commons.vfs.FileNotFolderException: Could not list the contents of "file:///Y:/20190728" because it is not a folder.
2019/07/28 23:45:04 - FileInputList -   at org.apache.commons.vfs.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(Unknown Source)
2019/07/28 23:45:04 - FileInputList -   at org.pentaho.di.core.fileinput.FileInputList.createFileList(FileInputList.java:243)
2019/07/28 23:45:04 - FileInputList -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.getfilenames.GetFileNamesMeta.getDynamicFileList(GetFileNamesMeta.java:679)
2019/07/28 23:45:04 - FileInputList -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.getfilenames.GetFileNames.processRow(GetFileNames.java:176)
2019/07/28 23:45:04 - FileInputList -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2019/07/28 23:45:04 - FileInputList -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2019/07/28 23:45:04 - Modified Java Script Value.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
```

Comment: Is your Y: driver correctly mapped ? And also, i suggest you upgrade to 7.0.0.0-25 ... very stable version, 5.3 is way too old.

Comment: I would also suggest upgrading the version of Pentaho. Version 8.3 was released recently, I'd give that a shot.

Comment: I tested in Pentaho 7, no luck with that. I need to try latest of Version 8.3